Can you use many smaller trimmer capacitors in place of one big one?
Been trying to find a large enough trimmer capacitor for an AM radio project (Going off this)
but I can't find any that have the capacitance that they're asking for. I know it would be a little unwieldy but could I use several smaller trimmer capacitors in parallel to achieve the same effect? Any other recommendations for the project?

You certainly can, and they do add, one consideration is that the minimum as well as maximum capacitance adds. So if you have a 5-20pF capacitor and parallel 10 of them you'll get 50pF to 200pF.
However, that's not a trimmer capacitor, it's an old-school tuning capacitor (often they have trimmers built in). Typically, in the heyday of discrete transistor AM radios they looked like this:

If you connect the two outer pins together you'll get the sum of the two capacitances. The one I linked is 60pF + 140pF = 200pF maximum total, you can find others. There are also trimcap screws on the back typically that add a small variable amount of capacitance to the total.
Their documentation is sparse to nonexistent so if you go that way you should be prepared to muck around with a capacitance meter to figure out what is what.

It is not very practical but possible.
Define what tuner cap. specs you need and [where] to shop is the preferred approach.
